# Table in a mathematical paper

Tags: tables

I write a paper for a course and have some trouble with a table. As you can see the table fits not well into the document:

[image]

It would be appreciated if someone could tell me how to fix this problem. Here is a test code:

```
% /usr/local/doc/tex-inputs/latex/notes/paper.tex

% An example showing how to prepare an article using AMSLaTeX.
% Stephen G. Simpson, Fall 1995.
% Please send any comments or questions to simpson@math.psu.edu.

% Lines beginning with a percent sign are comments.  LaTeX ignores them.

% Begin by declaring a document class and options.

\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{amsart}

% \documentclass{amsart} says to use the AMS article document class.
% [12pt,oneside] says to use the 12pt and oneside options.
% If you don't want these options, just say \documentstyle{amsart}.

% After the document class declaration comes the preamble.
% The preamble begins here.

   % First we activate any packages that we may need.
   %
   % The amssymb package provides \mathbb and other
   % math symbols.  The amsmath package provides sophisticated math
   % constructions.  The amsthm package provides \theoremstyle and
   % the \proof environment.
   %
   % The amsmath and amsthm packages are automatically activated by
   % \documentclass{amsart}, so there is no need to activate them here.

      \usepackage{amssymb}
      \usepackage{graphicx}   % if you want to include graphics files
      \usepackage{amsmath}
      \usepackage{amsthm}
      \usepackage{amsfonts}
      \usepackage[english]{babel}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage{enumerate}
      \usepackage{color}
      \usepackage[pdftex,citecolor=green,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
      \usepackage{aliascnt}
      \usepackage{tikz}



   % Next we use \newtheorem to specify our theorem-like environments
   % (theorem, definition, etc.) and how to display and number them.
   %
   % Note: The \theoremstyle declarations affect the appearance of the
   % Theorems, Definitions, etc.

      \theoremstyle{plain}
      \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
      \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
      \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

      \theoremstyle{definition}
      \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
       \theoremstyle{proposition}
      \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

      \theoremstyle{remark}
      \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

   % The preamble is also a good place to define new commands and macros.
   % This part of the preamble is strictly optional according to your taste.

      \newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}
      \newcommand{\nil}{\varnothing}

   % The following mysterious maneuver gets rid of AMS junk at the top
   % and bottom of the first page.

      \makeatletter
      \def\@setcopyright{}
      \def\serieslogo@{}
      \makeatother

% This ends the preamble.  We now proceed to the document itself.

\begin{document}




   \section{Test code}



\begin{proof}

 Together with the inductive result of Lemma \ref{induction} this implies in all cases that $\mathcal{P}$ is one of optimal, unbounded, or feasible:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|cc|p{2cm}cccp{2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{}               &            &                                                 & $\mathcal{P}/e$              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                   \\
                        &            & optimal                                         & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{unbonuded}      & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{infeasible}                                        \\ \hline
                        & optimal    & optimal Lemma \ref{induction} i)                & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(not possible)} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{optimal or infeasible Lemma \ref{induction} ii)}   \\ \cline{2-5} 
$\mathcal{P}\backslash e$ & unbounded  & unbounded or optimal Lemma \ref{induction} iii) & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{unbounded}      & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{unbounded or infeasible Lemma \ref{induction} iv)} \\ \cline{2-5} 
                        & infeasible & (not possible)                                  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{(not possible)} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{infeasible}                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{proof}
 \bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

You will get unresolved citation which doesn't matter.

Comment: Use `tabularx` package.

Comment: There are some unclear things. Do you want the *P/e* header on the left to encompass multiple rows or is it together with "unbounded" next to it? It might be helpful if you clarified how the cells are organized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you simplify the table structure as follows:

- Provide only four columns: The left-most one should be headed by `$\mathcal{P}\backslash e$`, and columns 2 to 4 should be headed by `$\mathcal{P}/e$`.
- Don't use a `tabular` but, instead, a `tabularx` environment, and make use of the `X` column type provided by this package. The `X` column type allows text to wrap. Put differently, don't use `c` as the column alignment specifier.
- Don't use full (left and right) justification; use left-justification instead.
- You're probably going to do this anyway, but I'll still suggest you provide a `\caption` for the `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % left-justified version of X column type
\begin{document}
\section{Test code}

Together with the inductive result of Lemma \ref{induction} this implies in all cases that $\mathcal{P}$ is one of optimal, unbounded, or feasible:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|*{3}{Y|}}
\hline
$\mathcal{P}\backslash e$ 
&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathcal{P}/e$}\\
\cline{2-4}
& optimal  &unbounded & infeasible \\ 
\hline
optimal 
& optimal Lemma \ref{induction} i) 
& (not possible)
& optimal or infeasible Lemma \ref{induction} ii)   \\ 
\hline
unbounded
& unbounded or optimal Lemma \ref{induction} iii) 
& unbounded
& unbounded or infeasible Lemma \ref{induction} iv) \\ 
\hline
infeasible 
& (not possible)                                  
& (not possible)
& infeasible \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum**: I'll make one more suggestion related to the overall design of the table: Don't use any vertical lines at all, and use the `booktabs` package and its commands for drawing well-spaced horizontal lines ("rules"):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % left-justified version of X column type
\begin{document}
\section{Test code}

Together with the inductive result of Lemma \ref{induction} this implies in all cases that $\mathcal{P}$ is one of optimal, unbounded, or feasible:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X*{3}{Y}@{}}
\toprule
$\mathcal{P}\backslash e$ 
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{$\mathcal{P}/e$}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& optimal  &unbounded & infeasible \\
\midrule
optimal 
& optimal Lemma \ref{induction} i) 
& (not possible)
& optimal or infeasible Lemma \ref{induction} ii)   \\[1ex]
unbounded
& unbounded or optimal Lemma \ref{induction} iii) 
& unbounded
& unbounded or infeasible Lemma \ref{induction} iv) \\[1ex]
infeasible 
& (not possible)                                  
& (not possible)
& infeasible \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

**Second addendum**: The OP has asked for a version of the table that features `$\mathcal{P}\backslash e$` by itself in a new column at the far-left. Here's an attempt to make this work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % left-justified version of X column type
\begin{document}
\section{Test code}

Together with the inductive result of Lemma \ref{induction} this implies in all cases that $\mathcal{P}$ is one of optimal, unbounded, or feasible:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|*{3}{Y|}}
\hline 
& &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathcal{P}/e$}\\
\cline{3-5}
& & optimal  &unbounded & infeasible \\ 
\hline
& optimal 
& optimal Lemma \ref{induction} i) 
& (not possible)
& optimal or infeasible Lemma \ref{induction} ii)   \\ 
\cline{2-5}
$\mathcal{P}\backslash e$
& unbounded
& unbounded or optimal Lemma \ref{induction} iii) 
& unbounded
& unbounded or infeasible Lemma \ref{induction} iv) \\ 
\cline{2-5}
& infeasible 
& (not possible)                                  
& (not possible)
& infeasible \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to have on the very left side another column for \mathcal{P}\backslash e$ like for $\mathcal{P}/e$ ?

Comment: @math - It's certainly *possible*. What do you want to place in the new (far-left) column, and what would remain in the currently left-most column?

Comment: In the very left should stand $\mathcal{P}\backslash e$ like on the very top row for $\mathcal{P}/e$. Such that both the very top row and the very left column look the same (for \mathcal{P}/e and \mathcal{P}\backslash e respectively.)

Comment: @math - please see the second addendum. I must confess I'm not sure I understand your objective in adding another column to the table.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|cc|XcccX|}
\hline
A & B & CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC & D & E & F & HHH HHH \\
A & B & CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC CCC & D & E & F & HHH HHH \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```